# Grunt, want to load different javascript files in different pages

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am not sure if this makes sense.
I just freshly learned Grunt and loved the idea of the way loading multiple javascript files into one single using Grunt.
Having learned Grunt, I wanted to load different javascript files in different pages.
For example, 
 - page_one.php needs to load js_a.js and js_b.js
 - page_two.php needs to load js_b.js and js_c.js

Can this be handled in Grunt and how do I do that in Grunt?

Can anyone give me some ideas how I can approach this?
or if this cannot be happening in Grunt, which one can be used for this scenario?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it definitely varies based on your situation. If all the js for the site are small and can somehow all coexist in the same file, I'd put them all together. On my larger sites, I have a global bundle and then other bundles for use in different areas of the site. The idea for the larger sites for me was to minimize the number of scripts the client downloaded while keeping the file a reasonable size.

Comment: @DarthDerrr, that's exactly what I try to do. If you do not mind, can you tell me more about how that can be setup as your scenario?